# mongo's replica set unbalanced

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongodb replica set, and now there is a problem. When I use mongostat, I found the master node as follows:

```
insert  query update delete getmore command flushes mapped  vsize    res faults
    *0     *0    148     *0     260    96|0       0   942g  1888g  28.2g    439
    *0     *0    351     *0     350   200|0       0   942g  1888g  28.2g    672
    *0     *0    350     *0     593   257|0       0   942g  1888g  28.2g   1319
    *0     *0    196     *0     328    99|0       0   942g  1888g  28.2g    679
    *0     *0    159     *0     255   105|0       0   942g  1888g  28.2g    551
    *0     *0    264     *0     329   184|0       0   942g  1888g  28.2g    466
    *0     *0    168     *0     312    96|0       0   942g  1888g  28.2g    588
    *0     *0    120     *0     227    70|0       0   942g  1888g  28.2g    396
    *0     *0    132     *0     236    72|0       0   942g  1888g  28.2g    441
```

and other nodes（secondaries）：

```
insert  query update delete getmore command flushes mapped  vsize    res faults 
  *364    659  *1353     *0       0   169|0       1   944g  1892g  28.7g   6852 
  *854    614  *1709     *0       0   169|0       0   944g  1892g  28.5g   6208 
  *603    484  *1320     *0       0   158|0       0   944g  1892g  28.6g   5383 
  *463    473  *1147     *0       0   152|0       0   944g  1892g  28.6g   5012 
  *343    488   *852     *0       0   130|0       0   944g  1892g  28.7g   4496 
  *614    654  *1187     *0       0   176|0       1   944g  1892g  28.7g   5058 
  *445    659  *1146     *0       0   183|0       0   944g  1892g  28.7g   5775 
   *58     43   *104     *0       0    18|0       0   944g  1892g  28.7g    299 
  *629    502  *1382     *0       0   152|0       0   944g  1892g  28.8g   4379 
   *94     42    *38     *0       0    11|0       0   944g  1892g  28.7g   1430 

insert  query update delete getmore command flushes mapped  vsize    res faults
   *28     44    *10     *0       0    11|0       0   944g  1892g  27.6g   2419
 *1520   1807  *3443     *0       0   592|0       0   944g  1892g  27.6g  14749
  *168     67     *8     *0       0    15|0       0   944g  1892g  27.5g   1660
 *1354   1920  *3471     *0       0   570|0       1   944g  1892g  27.5g  13817
   *14     53    *22     *0       0    21|0       0   944g  1892g  27.5g   2167
 *1526   2038  *3439     *0       0   575|0       1   944g  1892g  27.6g  14971
  *256     74    *42     *0       0    13|0       0   944g  1892g  27.4g   1385
 *1276   1796  *3427     *0       0   574|0       0   944g  1892g  27.5g  14610
   *94     52    *62     *0       0    13|0       0   944g  1892g  27.5g   1657
 *1544   1766  *3301     *0       0   507|0       1   944g  1892g  27.5g  11683
```

Separate read and write has been done, but not much to insert the master node, and there are a lot of inserts and updates in the slave nodes.  Why?

Comment: Most likely the secondaries were getting in sync with the primary.  One thing to note is that, if you run 1 update query against the primary that updates 100 documents, it'll be translated to 100 updates/inserts in the secondaries (one per document).

Comment: Were the secondaries fully up to date with the master when you run your set of queries to produce this? Also what queries were you running?

Comment: THX. GET query is the most, and set is deployed together.Can you think of any other reason for it @Sammaye

Comment: THX. That not like this reason, becasue the most operation is to GET a document, and modify the document, and save. Do you think there are other reasons? @AnandJayabalan

Comment: Can you add a rs.status() to the question?